# "No qualifying bean of type" for JPA repository in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data

I am implementing Rest API with Spring Boot. Since my entity classes are from a package from another package, I had to specify that with annotation `EntityScan`. Also, I used `EnableJpaRepositories` to specify the package where JPA repository is defined. Here is what my project looks like:

[image]

```
//Application.java

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
@EntityScan("org.mdacc.rists.cghub.model")
@EnableJpaRepositories("org.mdacc.rists.cghub.ws.repository")
```

In my controller class I had a SeqService object autowired.

```
//SeqController.java

@Autowired private SeqService seqService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/api/seqs", method = GET, produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<List<SeqTb>> getSeqs() {
    List<SeqTb> seqs = seqService.findAll();
    return new ResponseEntity<List<SeqTb>>(seqs, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

`SeqService` is an interface from which I created a Bean class for that `SeqServiceBean`. In the `SeqServiceBean` I autowired the JPA repository:

```
// SeqServiceBean.java

@Autowired private SeqRepository seqRepository;

@Override
public List<SeqTb> findAll() {
    List<SeqTb> seqs = seqRepository.findAll();
    return seqs;
}

//SeqRepository.java

@Repository
public interface SeqRepository extends JpaRepository<SeqTb, Integer> {

    @Override
    public List<SeqTb> findAll();

    public SeqTb findByAnalysisId(String analysisId);
}
```

However the application couldn't start due to the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.mda.rists.cghub.ws.repository.SeqRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
```

I don't understand the error. What does it have to do with qualifying bean?

Comment: It basically says, it can't find the eligible `SeqRepository` instance to autowire. Add your project structure and some repository related code.

Comment: refactor Application.java annotations delete all  use this @SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan({"org.mdacc.rists.cghub.model"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"org.mdacc.rists.cghub.ws.repository"})

Comment: @kakashi hatake  tried what you suggested and still the same error

Comment: @AliDehghani Added project structure and repository class.

Comment: Can you move your `Application` into `org.mda` package and delete all the `EntityScan` and `EnableJpaRepositories`?

Comment: @AliDehghani It doesn't work. `Not an managed type: class org.mdacc.rists.cghub.model.SeqTb` I forgot to mention that the package where my entity classes are defined resides in a separate package. So I think `entityscan` is necessary.

Comment: Keep the `EntityScan`, move the `Application` into `org.mda` and delete the `EnableJpaRepository`..

Comment: @AliDehghani Deleted `EnableJpaRepository` and it worked, even if I change the package back to `org.mda.rists.cghub.ws`. What's wrong with that Jpa annotation?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You were scanning the wrong package in your `EnableJpaRepositories`. There is no `org.mdacc.rists.cghub.ws.repository` package. So, use this instead:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories("org.mda.rists.cghub.ws.repository")
```

Spring Boot does not require any specific code layout to work, however, there are some best practices that will help you. Check out the [spring boot documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-structuring-your-code) on best practices of structuring your code.

Comment: Where should this annotation be added? Repository class? `WebApplicationInitializerClass`? Something else

Comment: why should we add this annotation? I thought spring will scan the packages by itself!